# Proper way to define java.util.Queue bean in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I faced with a strange error when I tried to inject a `java.util.Queue` bean using `Spring Core`.

I made a quick code example:

```java
@Configuration public class Main {
    @Autowired private Queue<Service> serviceQueue;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Main.class);
        Main bean = context.getBean(Main.class);
        System.out.println(bean.serviceQueue.size());
    }

    @Bean public Queue<Service> serviceQueue() {
        Queue<Service> serviceQueue = new ArrayDeque<>();
        serviceQueue.add(serviceImpl1());
        serviceQueue.add(serviceImpl2());
        return serviceQueue;
    }

    @Bean public Service serviceImpl1() { return new ServiceImpl1(); }
    @Bean public Service serviceImpl2() { return new ServiceImpl2(); }

    public interface Service {}
    public static class ServiceImpl1 implements Service {}
    public static class ServiceImpl2 implements Service {}
}
```

When I run this code, I receive the next error in console:

```
Feb 23, 2023 8:59:48 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext refresh
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'main': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'serviceQueue'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedValues' to required type 'java.util.Queue'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedValues' to required type 'java.util.Queue': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'main': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'serviceQueue'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedValues' to required type 'java.util.Queue'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedValues' to required type 'java.util.Queue': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:93)
    at app.Main.main(Main.java:16)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedValues' to required type 'java.util.Queue'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedValues' to required type 'java.util.Queue': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterSupport.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterSupport.java:45)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1471)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedValues' to required type 'java.util.Queue': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:262)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterSupport.java:73)
    ... 20 more
```

Could you please explain why I can't create a `Queue` like this? If I replace `Queue` with `List`, everything will work.

Thank you.

Comment: Am I reading this correctly - you want to autowire `serviceQueue` in the component it is created? Also, does it change anything if `ServiceImpl1` and `ServiceImpl2` are not Spring beans? Also, does adding `@Qualifier("serviceQueue")` (and changing `@Bean` to `@Bean("serviceQueue")`) change anything?

Comment: @dan1st, it's just a quick code example that reproduces my issue. In my real project all implementations stored in different java files. But the error is the same.

Comment: @dan1st, if I add `@Qualifier("serviceQueue")` and `@Bean("serviceQueue")`, I'll receive a new error message:

`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.util.Queue<app.Service>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier("serviceQueue")}`

Comment: Is the `@Bean` definition in a component managed by Spring?

Comment: @dan1st, how can I check this?

Comment: Is that class/component annotated with `@Component` or a similar stereorype annotation? Is it in the one of the packages scanned by Spring? Can you autowire it in other classes=

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252090/discussion-between-yevhen-vasyliev-and-dan1st).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me summarize the insights [from chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/252090) in this answer and add a few things.

## Why does it work with `List`?

When autowiring a `List<X>`, Spring automatically gives you a `List` containing all Spring-managed beans that can be assigned to `X` as described in [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-injecting-collections).

So, Spring doesn't give you the `List` you created but it creates its own `List` containing all registered beans of type `Service` and doesn't give you the one created by you.

## The error with `Queue`

Knowing that, we can also explain the error you are receiving:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedValues' to required type 'java.util.Queue': no matching editors or conversion strategy found

It tried to autowire the `List<Service>` containing all registered `Service` beans but that wasn't a `Queue`.

## `@Resource` to the rescue

You can explicitely specify the bean to be autowired using [`javax.annotation.Resource`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/annotation/resource) (Spring 5/Spring Boot 2/Java EE) or [`jakarta.annotation.Resource`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/9/apidocs/jakarta/annotation/resource) (Spring 6/Spring Boot 3/Jakarta EE):

```java
@Resource(name = "serviceQueue")
private Queue<Service> serviceQueue;
```

```java
@Bean("serviceQueue")
public Queue<Service> serviceQueue() {
    Queue<Service> serviceQueue = new ArrayDeque<>();
    serviceQueue.add(serviceImpl1());
    serviceQueue.add(serviceImpl2());
    return serviceQueue;
}
```

This tells Spring explicitly to use the `Queue` defined by you.

## Alternatives

### Constructor injection and `@Order`

If you don't need the same `Queue` in multiple places, you could use constructor autowiring and create the `Queue` in the constructor:

```java
@Configuration
public class Main {
    private Queue<Service> serviceQueue;
    @Autowired
    public Main(List<Service> services){
        serviceQueue = new ArrayDequeue<>(services);
    }
}
```

```
@Bean
@Order(1)
public Service serviceImpl1() {
    return new ServiceImpl1();
}
@Bean
@Order(2)
public Service serviceImpl2() {
    return new ServiceImpl2();
}
```

### Don't make the implementations beans

You could also try to remove `@Bean` from `serviceImpl1()` and `serviceImpl2()` so that Spring doesn't attempt to create a `List` of it by itself.

Note that I haven't tested this approach.

Comment: `@Autowired @Qualifier("serviceQueue") private Queue<Service> serviceQueue;` also worked for me.

I asked the same question to Spring devs, and now `Queue` autowiring support is planned in `6.1.x` release: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/30022